# Determine if an HTML div is clickable

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium, listener, robotframework

I'm working on some Selenium/Robot Framework automated testing, and I need a way to automate locating `div` tags that are clickable.

The **Click Element** keyword does the trick if I give it a very specific CSS selector, but how can I algorithmically find an element that can be clicked? As long as there is a way to get the DOM node, I'm hoping to return a unique selector that I can use to call the **Click Element** keyword.

I understand that old versions of jQuery have `$(element).data('events')` that might be used to find click listeners, but it seems like an unreliable method. Moreover, the Chrome web inspector doesn't seem to recognize any `click` listeners for the `div`s that I'm looking at.

For completeness, here is an example of the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div id="contentarea" class="">
  <div id="contentwrapper" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="rap">
      <div id="twocol" class="clearfix margintop">
        <div class="leftcol scrollable addprogram">
          <a href="..." class="newgroup">
            <span class="addicon"></span>New Group
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightcol clearfix">
          <ul class="subtabs rounded clearfix">
            <li data-tab="pending" class="selected">
              <a href="..." class="selected">Released</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div id="program-grid" class="clearfix" style="">
            <div class="program groups" tabindex="0">
              <div class="programframe"></div>
              <div class="programinfo">
                <h1 class="prizeheight">Development</h1>
              </div>
              </div><div class="program groups" tabindex="0">
              <div class="programframe"></div>
              <div class="programinfo">
                <h1 class="prizeheight">Loss Prevention/Safety Group</h1>
              </div>
... 
...
```

**`<div class='program groups'>` is a clickable element** that I hope to identify programmatically.

For the record, the HTML is valid and so on. Minified Javascript somehow renders this source, and probably attaches the listeners.

Thanks!

Comment: If you could post an example of the HTML you're working with, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not possible according to [this website](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

> Which event handlers are registered?
>
> One problem of the current implementation of W3C’s event registration
>   model is that you can’t find out if any event handlers are already
>   registered to an element. In the traditional model you could do:
>
> alert(element.onclick) and you see the function that’s registered to
>   it, or undefined if nothing is registered. Only in its very recent DOM
>   Level 3 Events W3C adds an eventListenerList to store a list of event
>   handlers that are currently registered on an element. This
>   functionality is not yet supported by any browser, it’s too new.
>   However, the problem has been addressed.
>
> Fortunately removeEventListener() doesn’t give any errors if the event
>   listener you want to remove has not been added to the element, so when
>   in doubt you can always use removeEventListener().